# Differences when extracting day of week from Python and PostgreSQL, any solution?

Tags: python, postgresql

My code on PostgreSQL:

```
select extract(dow from date '2021-01-25')
-----------------------------------------
date_part
    1
```

My code on Python:

```
a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-25', '%Y-%m-%d')
print(a.weekday())
-------------------------------------------
0
```

p/s: my database set day of week following the `PostgreSQL` so 0 is wrong and 1 is correct

I accidentally and stupidity, change my code python to `+1` before running the query.

Well it works but it will crash soon by the weekend. I wonder if there is any better solution than creating an `if` `else` statement.

I suppose the `datetime` library of Python do not use the same standard with the database `PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SELECT EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2021-01-24');` on Postgres and `a.isoweekday()` in Python.
In both cases you get Monday=1 to Sunday=7.

Comment: provided, I need to change my `python` code to the format of 1:Monday, 0:Sunday. Is there any way to do so ? Obviously not using `if`

Comment: You can always do modulo 7.  a.isoweekday()%7 in python and SELECT MOD(EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2021-01-25')::INT,7) in Postgres